# Where are scripts in injectScripts injected in TestCafé tests?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, inject, testcafe

I am setting up TestCafé tests programmatically and I use the `injectScripts` config on the `Runner` class to inject functions.
According to the documentation, these scripts are added to the header of the tested page. Is it possible to invoke the functions from the test itself? I haven't found a way to do it.
I can see that the scripts map is accessible inside the test and I can log out the content by doing

```js
console.log(t.testRun.opts.clientScripts)
```

But it would be utterly ugly to parse this map and eval the scripts...
How can I, or can I be precise, invoke an injected function from the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions) or [`eval`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#one-time-client-code-execution) APIs to address injected scripts or any other client script from a test. Please take a look at the following example:

```js
const scriptContent = `
function alertHelloWorld () {
    alert('Hello world!');
}`;

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `https://example.com`
    .clientScripts({ content: scriptContent });

test('New Test', async t => {
    await t.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true);

    await t.eval(() => alertHelloWorld());

    const history = await t.getNativeDialogHistory();

    await t
        .expect(history[0].type).eql('alert')
        .expect(history[0].text).eql('Hello world!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into `ClientFunction`, looks like it can solve my problems.

Comment: Didn't get it to work though, tried both `ClientFunction` and `eval` with no luck. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4309