# How can I inject parameters into a TestCafé test?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, inject, testcafe

**Scenario:**

I run TestCafé wrapped in code, using the API 
I have a test I want to parameterize, testing with different dynamic values.

**Problem**

Testcafé has no support for sending parameters to a test. Is there a way to inject values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way! The `clientScripts` feature can be used to send in parameters. The documentation is very well written how to inject scripts. It took me some time to figure out how to use it from within the test so hopefully this will bring you on the right track.

1. Create a data object with your params
2. Add the JSON to a small JS code block representing a function
3. Inject the code block to your runner/fixture/test with the `.clientScripts` setter
4. `eval` the code in your test et voilá! You have the parameters

```
// Create the data object
let data = {aString: 'Yo!', aNumber: 345}

// Add it to a String value representing a JS function
const scriptContent = `
  function getParameters() {
    return ${JSON.stringify(data)};
  }`

// Invoke the test runner with the code block as content
testcafe('localhost').then(cafe => {
    cafe.createRunner()
      .src('mytest.js')
      .clientScripts({ content: scriptContent })
      .run()
      //...and so on...
})
```

Now, when the test is executed the getParameters function exists *inside the page head*. This code can be evaluated or invoked with a `ClientFunction` or a `t.eval`:

```
let x = await t.eval( () => getParameters() );
console.log(x);
await t.expect(x.aString).eql('Yo!', 'Not Okey, mKay?')
```

An answer with a fully [working example can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012508/where-are-scripts-in-injectscripts-injected-in-testcaf%C3%A9-tests).

Comment: I think OP, like me, is asking for a way to pass configuration from the runner into the test case, not into the page under test.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) to pass parameters to TestCafe tests from your runner script.

```js
//test.js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

(async => {
   process.env.foo = 'bar';

   const testcafe = await createTestCafe();

   await testcafe
       .createRunner()
       .src('test.js')
       .browsers('chrome')
       .run();

   await testcafe.close();
})()
```

```js
//test.js
fixture `Examples`;

test('process.env', async t => {
    console.log(process.env.foo);
});
```

Comment: Using `process.env` means the parameters are available globally, right?

Comment: Yes, values stored in `process.env` are available globally. If you want to store some information that is specific for some test, you can use an object and `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` functions. Take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/431c7c7cc610a6329df12959da235b9b

Comment: Very nice. As the questions says these tests are executed programmatically and encapsulating the parameters (not leaking globally) is very much preferred in our case.