# Testcafe tests - conditional skip/run

Tags: conditional-statements, testcafe, skip

I have some tests added, which are related to user account. I need to confirm that the test user exists for proceeding to the further tests
This is what I have done,
1.Created a method to verify whether the user exists which returns true if user exists.This is done by logging in backend . So need to run only onces.
2. Called this method in test.before
But I need to run all tests only if the user exists, else skip all tests. Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

At present, this feature is not implemented (a related issue on GitHub - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1626). However, you can achieve your goal without it by splitting your test run into two separate runs. The first test part is creating a test user, the second one - all tests that required a test user. Test runs can look as follows:

```
testcafe chrome tests/create-test-user.js // creates the user

testcafe chrome !/tests/create-test-user.js /tests/**/*.js // run all tests except test that creates the user
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the suggestion. But other than this , do we have any other option to achieve this? For example, is there any way to get the value the same parameter in different tests in testcafe?

Comment: You can pass parameters to TestCafe tests in a lot of ways: environment variables, JSON files, global variables, etc. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075755/how-can-i-inject-parameters-into-a-testcaf%C3%A9-test) for more information.